# Build and upload jar to jcenter

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, jcenter

I've created a library for Android and now I would like to publish it. I have followed [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) guide and got it to work on jcenter and I'm able to use it.

The uploaded file, however, is an `*.aar` file.

How can I get it to compile and upload a `.jar`?

Answer (score 2):

The Gradle project in the blog post you refer to is an Android library project, that's why it creates aar file.

For example of a Java project (that create a jar), take a look at [Bintray's GitHub examples repository](https://github.com/bintray/bintray-examples). If you work with Gradle, probably the 
`gradle-bintray-plugin-examples/publications-example/` will be the right one to begin with.